# Getting "SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER" on Proxied Get Request with http.client in Python

Tags: python, proxy, get, http.client

I am attempting to send a proxied post request with http.client, and I am getting `SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER` error.

Below is my current code:

```
r = http.client.HTTPSConnection("IP:PORT")
r.request('GET', f"http://httpbin.org/get" , headers={"host": "httpbin.org"})
res = r.getresponse()
print(res.read().decode())
```

It is currently returning an SSL error. `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)`.